# Seeking a closed form for $\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} y^{(n-2k)^2}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to find a closed form for this sum:
$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} e^{(n-2k)^2 x}
= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} y^{(n-2k)^2} \quad\text{for}\ y = e^x$$
as a function of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $y = e^x$ of degree $n^2$, i.e., $f_n = b_n y^{n^2} + b_{n-2} y^{(n-2)^2} + \cdots$.

**Added background**: This sum arises in a physical problem that reduces to evaluating the average of $\cos^n \theta$:
$$f_n(-\sigma^2/2) = \overline{\cos^n \theta} = \int_{\Gamma} d\theta P(\theta) \cos^n \theta,$$
where $\Gamma$ is any interval of length $2\pi$ and $P(\theta)$ is the wrapped normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$:
$$P(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(\theta + 2\pi j)^2 / 2 \sigma^2} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k \theta - k^2 \sigma^2 /2}.$$

I would guess that the way to find a closed form (if it exists) is by using the Egorychev method (as described in [these notes](http://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/papers/egorychev.pdf) by [Marko Riedel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44883/marko-riedel)), but I'm not skillful enough to do this myself.

As a side note, this sum can be reformulated as the series:
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} C(m,n) x^m, \quad C(m,n) = \frac{1}{m! 2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (n-2k)^{2m},$$
where the coefficients $C(m,n)$ are a bit similar to the Stirling numbers of the second kind, but still different.

**Added**: $C(m,n)$ is itself a polynomial of degree $m$ of variable $n$, which has the form:
$$C(m,n) = \sum_{p=1}^{m} a_p n^p ,$$
where $a_m = (2m-1)!!/m!$ and $a_0$ is always zero. Formally, $C(m,n)$ can be expressed in terms of the generalized hypergeometric function:
$$C(m,n) = \frac{n^{2m}}{m! 2^n} {}_{2m+1}\! F_{2m}\bigg(\underbrace{1 - \frac{n}{2}, \ldots, 1 - \frac{n}{2}}_{2m\ \mathrm{times}}, -n; \underbrace{-\frac{n}{2}, \ldots, -\frac{n}{2}}_{2m\ \mathrm{times}};-1 \bigg),$$
which is formally valid only for odd $n$ ($-n/2 \notin \mathbb{Z}$), but for even $n$ singularities in $\Gamma$ functions cancel out.

Comment: It is a polynomial in $e^x$. I doubt it has any "closed form".

Comment: "It is a polynomial in $e^x$" — That's obvious. The question is does this polynomial has a name or maybe is a particular case of some special function?

Comment: The exponential is a bit of a distraction, since $\exp((n-2k)^2x)=y^{(n-2k)^2}$, where $y=e^x$. If you can get a closed form in $y$, then you can substitute $y\to e^x$.

Comment: I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom kn y^{(n-2k)^2}=2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom k{n} y^{(n-2k)^2}$$

Comment: Come to think of it, you can do even better ...
$$\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}y^{(n-2k)^2}=\frac{y^{n^2}}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}y^{-4nk+4k^2}=\frac{\exp(xn^2)}{2^n}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}w^{k(n-k)}$$ where $w:=1/y^4=\exp(-4x)$. Now, the multiplied factor is a non-issue, and the remaining summation looks like the kind of thing that *should* simplify ... somehow.

Comment: @Blue: the exponent of $y$ is a quadratic function, making it very unlikely to find a closed-form solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: True enough. *Closed form* might be a bit much to ask, but the "$w$ form" in my comment at least looks a little cleaner. :)

Comment: I even failed to find anywhere in the literature a consideration of polynomials of the general form $\sum_k c_k y^{k^2}$. However, I'm definitely not an expert in this area, so it is likely I could have missed it.

Comment: @Blue This expression reminds me of this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299304/a-family-of-polynomials-whose-zeros-all-lie-on-the-unit-circle

Comment: Thanks! One of the comments on that question also has a link to another related one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296465/on-the-polynomial-sum-k-0n-binomnk-1kxkn-k